# CSS - Problem between white-space and webkit-line-clamp

Tags: css

I have this problem.
I have 3 lines of text and ellipsis. I need the complete words and not cut them, but if I add the white-space nowrap the line is converted to only 1. Any help? is a compatibility problem?
**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/vxfy0Lna/1/

```css
.clinic-description {
   font-family: OpenSans, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
  
}
```

```html
<span class="clinic-description" id="testObject">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore12345678 magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </span>
```

Comment: When you use `white-space: nowrap` it forces the browser not to break the line into >1 line at all... that's what it's for. If you are using a multiline clamp then you shouldn't disable wrapping.

Comment: @Terry and is another option to not cut the words ?

Comment: Do you mean you don't want the last word shown to be cut-off midword?

Comment: @Terry exactly, the last and all the words if is possible

Comment: Don't think that's possible *yet*: right now line clamp will truncate mid-text unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this mixin

```
@mixin multiLineEllipsis($lineHeight: 1.2em, $lineCount: 1, $bgColor: white){
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  line-height: $lineHeight;
  max-height: $lineHeight * $lineCount; 
  text-align: justify;
  margin-right: -1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  &:before {
    content: '...';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  &:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    margin-top: 0.2em;
    background: $bgColor;
  }
}

.block-with-text {
  @include multiLineEllipsis($lineHeight: 1.2em, $lineCount: 3, $bgColor: white);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a single line clamp with a prefixed word at the beginning, I combined Flexbox, line-clamp & some span nesting, to get my desired effect.

Flexbox was needed to stop the 2nd span from pushing to the next line, and to also force the first span to always display at 100% of it's content-size.

```css
.text-style-small {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  
  .prefix-text {
    flex: 0 1 1;
  }

  .text-truncation {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    word-break: break-word;
    flex: 1 0 0;
  }
}

.wrapper {
  width: 180px;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  padding: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="text-style-small">
    <span class="prefix-text">Paypal:</span>
    <span class="text-truncation">frank.drebin@policequad.com.au</span>
  </button>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="text-style-small">
    <span class="prefix-text">Credit-card:</span>
    <span class="text-truncation">frank.drebin@policequad.com.au</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="text-style-small">
    <span class="prefix-text">Paypal:</span>
    <span class="text-truncation">frank.drebin@policequad.com.au</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

```
.text-style-small {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;

  .prefix-text {
    flex: 0 1 1;
  }

  .text-truncation {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    word-break: break-word;
    flex: 1 0 0;
  }
}

// for display purposes only
.wrapper {
  width: 180px;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  padding: 20px;
}
```